# Convert json string response to pojo

Tags: java, json, pojo

I am calling an API using rest template like below:

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, String.class);
```

And here is the json response string that i receive from the API

```
{
    "data": {
        "individuals": [
            {
                "cust_xref_id": "abf",
                "cust_frd_alrt_in": "n",
                "cust_satis_trd_ct": "4",
                "gam_open_rv_trd_ct": "4",
                "cust_extnl_delinq_90_day_ct": "1",
                "cust_extnl_delinq_in": "y"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

how can i map this response into a pojo? please help.

Comment: use [jsonschema2pojo.org](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), select "Source type: JSON" and "Annotation Style: Gson", paste in your json, and press "Preview"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Required classes for the conversion are below,

**1. DataDTO**

```
public class DataDTO {
private IndividualList data;

public IndividualList getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(IndividualList data) {
    this.data = data;
}}
```

**2. IndividualList**

```
public class IndividualList {

private List<IndividualDTO> individuals;

public List<IndividualDTO> getIndividuals() {
    return individuals;
}

public void setIndividuals(List<IndividualDTO> individuals) {
    this.individuals = individuals;
}}
```

**3. IndividualDTO**

```
public class IndividualDTO {

@JsonProperty("cust_xref_id")
private String custXrefId;
@JsonProperty("cust_frd_alrt_in")
private String custFrdAlrtIn;
@JsonProperty("cust_satis_trd_ct")
private String custSatisTrdCt;
@JsonProperty("gam_open_rv_trd_ct")
private String gamOpenRvTrdCt;

@JsonProperty("cust_extnl_delinq_90_day_ct")
private String custExtnlDelinq90DayCt;
@JsonProperty("cust_extnl_delinq_in")
private String custExtnlDelinqIn;

public String getCustXrefId() {
    return custXrefId;
}

public void setCustXrefId(String custXrefId) {
    this.custXrefId = custXrefId;
}

public String getCustFrdAlrtIn() {
    return custFrdAlrtIn;
}

public void setCustFrdAlrtIn(String custFrdAlrtIn) {
    this.custFrdAlrtIn = custFrdAlrtIn;
}

public String getCustSatisTrdCt() {
    return custSatisTrdCt;
}

public void setCustSatisTrdCt(String custSatisTrdCt) {
    this.custSatisTrdCt = custSatisTrdCt;
}

public String getGamOpenRvTrdCt() {
    return gamOpenRvTrdCt;
}

public void setGamOpenRvTrdCt(String gamOpenRvTrdCt) {
    this.gamOpenRvTrdCt = gamOpenRvTrdCt;
}

public String getCustExtnlDelinq90DayCt() {
    return custExtnlDelinq90DayCt;
}

public void setCustExtnlDelinq90DayCt(String custExtnlDelinq90DayCt) {
    this.custExtnlDelinq90DayCt = custExtnlDelinq90DayCt;
}


public String getCustExtnlDelinqIn() {
    return custExtnlDelinqIn;
}

public void setCustExtnlDelinqIn(String custExtnlDelinqIn) {
    this.custExtnlDelinqIn = custExtnlDelinqIn;
}}
```

**Tested Response:**

```
{"data":{"individuals":[{"cust_xref_id":"abf","cust_frd_alrt_in":"n","cust_satis_trd_ct":"4","gam_open_rv_trd_ct":"4","cust_extnl_delinq_90_day_ct":"1","cust_extnl_delinq_in":"y"}]}}
```